# Virtual Box With Arch Linux Host & Windows 10 Guest: Guest Does Not Support Native Resolution

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution, arch-linux

I use **Arch Linux** (Kernel: 4.17.2-1-ARCH) with Gnome 3.28.2. Along with Virtual Box I have installed the following packages:

```
virtualbox-host-modules-arch  5.2.12-10
virtualbox-guest-modules-arch  5.2.12-10
virtualbox-guest-utils  5.2.12-2
virtualbox-guest-iso  5.2.12-1
```

Using **Virtual Box** I have a guest with **Windows 10** 64 bit. 
I have installed the guest additions on the Windows 10 box.

The guest OS works fine, however, it supports only a small number of resolutions. Specifically the following:

[image: Guest Available Resolutions]

However my native resolutions is 1920x1080.

When using VirtualBox's menu ***View -> Virtual Screen 1*** I can see all available resolutions (including 1920x1080), however, selecting them does nothing.

I have also tried the guide provided by the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Set_optimal_framebuffer_resolution). Specifically, I have run the command:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "Windows10" "CustomVideoMode1" "1920x1080x32"
```

and

```
VBoxManage setextradata "Windows10" "Virtual Screen 1" "1920x1080x32"
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is Win10 the guest os? Your link is for arch guest.

Comment: @biswapriyo Arch is the host, Windows is the guest. Ok, my bad, that explains why this specific thing does not work. What about the rest thought?

Comment: (1) Try to increase Visual RAM (VRAM) in the virtual machine by example `VBoxManage modifyvm "Name of VM" --vram 1024`, depending on your RAM amount. (2) In VirtualBox menu File > Preferences > Display, set “Maximum guest screen size” to “None” ([link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/windows-guest-virtualbox-wont-increase-resolution-beyond-gjoko-pargo/)).

Comment: Output of `VBoxManage getextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution` ?

Comment: @harrymc `VBoxManage modifyvm "Name of VM" --vram 1024` outputs `Invalid RAM size: 1024 MB (must be in range [0, 256] MB)`, even though the host has 16GB of RAM. 

Also, interestingly, there is no "VirtualBox menu File > Preferences > Display, set “Maximum guest screen size”" option in my version. Maybe this option has been removed in the latest versions of Virtual Box?

Comment: @ssnobody `error: Invalid parameter 'global'`

Comment: Try : (1) In the virtual machine's Settings > Display to uncheck "Enable 3D Acceleration". (2) While the VM is running, enter on the host `VBoxManage controlvm "Name of VM" setvideomodehint 1920 1080 32`.

Comment: @Aventinus: Any comments ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- In the virtual machine's *Settings > Display*, uncheck
  "Enable 3D Acceleration" and see if this helps.
- While the virtual machine is turned off, enter :

  ```
  VBoxManage modifyvm "Name of VM" --vram 256
  ```
- While the virtual machine is turned off, in VirtualBox menu
  *File > Preferences > Display*, set "Maximum guest screen size" to "None"
  ([link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/windows-guest-virtualbox-wont-increase-resolution-beyond-gjoko-pargo/)).
- While the VM is running, enter on the host :

  ```
  VBoxManage controlvm "Name of VM" setvideomodehint 1920 1080 32
  ```

If nothing helps, try reinstalling VirtualBox.

Comment: I have unchecked 3D Acceleration. I ran `VBoxManage modifyvm "Name of VM" --vram 256`. There is `Maximum guest screen size` option. Definitely not as the link implies. Maybe is has been removed in the latest versions? I also `VBoxManage controlvm "Name of VM" setvideomodehint 1920 1080 32`. None of these things work.

Comment: This is not normal. Have you installed the guest additions in the Windows 10 VM? They are not required on the host and can maybe be uninstalled. If everything fails, uninstall VirtualBox, clean up its folders and reinstall.

Comment: I have installed the Guest Additions in the Windows 10 VM, yes. I guess the only option is to reinstall and see how it goes.

Comment: How is it going?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to install VirtualBox Guest Additions from https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/. Choose your VB version, download VBoxGuestAdditions_xxx.iso (host OS), mount iso and install.