# How can I change the list of resolutions for VirtualBox (host menu)?

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, display-settings

I have a quite big monitor and using different VMs in window mode - not full screen.
In VirtualBox (6.1) I often change the resolution of the guest via the Display > Virtual Monitor 1-Menu. There's a long list (12 items) of available resolutions from 640x480 to 1920x1200. These are all common resolutions with a ratio of 4:3, 16:9 and 16:10 but most of them are irrelevant for me. So I would like to

- remove unnecessary resolutions
- add new ones (e.g. 3:2 ratio resolutions)

I did not find any helpful advice online. Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance. Knut

P.S.: I'm not talking about adding new resolutions for the guest so that may be selected in the VM graphical controller, but the outside menu from the host. I.E. my question is not answered yet!

[image] This is a screenshot from the menu (it's in german but it should be clear, what I mean)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a display mode to a VirtualBox VM?](https://superuser.com/questions/451962/how-to-add-a-display-mode-to-a-virtualbox-vm). Also [this](https://superuser.com/questions/579819/virtualbox-4-2-10-auto-resize-not-working-will-auto-resize-down-but-not-up-unle) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1334372/virtual-box-with-arch-linux-host-windows-10-guest-guest-does-not-support-nati).

Comment: Hi @harrymc, no unfortunately not. The most answers concentrate on additional resolutions to add in the guest. I'm using the resolution list from the host menu.

Comment: Then your question is unclear. Host & VM are distinct.

Comment: @harrymc No, not on my system. Windows 10 Pro is the host, Linux is the Guest. I have on the one hand a VirtualBox menu called "Display > Virtual Monitor 1" with a predefined list of resolutions (you can also change the scaling there). This is "outside" the guest. Adding a new resolution like in the duplicate is not adding a resolution in this menu. But it's adding a resolution in the display configuration of my Linux. But this is not my aim.

Comment: I suggest cleaning up your post, perhaps adding some screenshots. You edited it, so it is already entered automatically into the Review queue, so make it very clear for the reviewers.